# IndexError: Traceback (most recent call last)

Tags: python

```
d = list(range(10, 20))
total5 = 0
v = 0
while d[v] > 0:
    total5 += d[v]
    v += 1
    print(total5)

    # what is the problem with this code?
```

this is the code to print the sum of numbers from 11 to 20

Comment: `d[v]` is always greater than 0. So it `v += 1` is executed everytime, and it goes out of bounds. But what exactly are you trying to do here ?

Comment: make the while statment to this - `while d[v] > 0 and v < 10`

Comment: Unless you are juts trying to get a feel for `while` loop, don't don't this. Instead consider doing something like `sum(range(10, 20))` ?

Answer (score 1):

First, `range` stops before the second parmeter(not include 20). So the return value of `range(10, 20)` is `numbers from 10 to 19`.

To calculate the sum, you can modify the while statement as followed.

```
d = list(range(10, 20))
total5 = 0
v = 0

while v < len(d):
    total5 += d[v]
    v += 1
    print(total5)
```

Comment: This is correction to question code. As i mention also there has to one  break point like length of list. Upvoted

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sum` of list function in python to get output:

```
d = list(range(10, 20))
print(d)
total5 = 0
v = 0

print(sum(d))
```

In your you increment is not stopping there has to be one break point like upto length of list you can keep incrementing. In your it will be always greater than 0 and this error say index out of range means more than length of list.